# How to clear a custom TableModel that extends AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Exactly what the question states. I created a custom `tableModel` class and I want to clear the `JTable` associated with that model on an `actionPerformed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the data from the TableModel used for the table.

If using the DefaultTableModel, just set the row count to zero. This will delete the rows and fire the TableModelEvent to update the GUI.

```
JTable table;

…
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

model.setRowCount(0);
```

If using other TableModel please check the documentation.